# MvxImageViewLoader not reloading larger images

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am having a strange problem with the MvxImageViewLoader. When I load image (400K in size) it loads fine for the first time but if I re-enter the same view and reload the image during ViewDidLoad it shows up empty. If I change the image path to a thumbnail image (23k in size) it loads without problem even if I re-enter the view. This is how I am loading the image

```
var frame = UIScreen.MainScreen.ApplicationFrame;
var myImage = new UIImageView
{
  Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, frame.Width, frame.Height)             
};
View.Add(myImage);            

var myImageLoader = new MvxImageViewLoader(() => myImage);
this.CreateBinding(myImageLoader).To<MyViewModel>(m => m.MyImagePath).Apply();
```

I am using the download cache and here is the part from the setup.cs file:

```
protected override void AddPluginsLoaders(MvxLoaderPluginRegistry registry)
{                  
    registry.AddConventionalPlugin<Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache.Touch.Plugin>();
    registry.AddConventionalPlugin<Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.File.Touch.Plugin>();
    base.AddPluginsLoaders(registry);
}

protected override void InitializeLastChance()
{
        Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache.PluginLoader.Instance.EnsureLoaded();
        Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.File.PluginLoader.Instance.EnsureLoaded();
        Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Json.PluginLoader.Instance.EnsureLoaded();

        var configuration = MvxDownloadCacheConfiguration.Default;

        var fileDownloadCache = new MvxFileDownloadCache(
            configuration.CacheName,
            configuration.CacheFolderPath,
            configuration.MaxFiles,
            configuration.MaxFileAge);

        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxFileDownloadCache>(fileDownloadCache);

        base.InitializeLastChance();
    }
```

I tried debugging with the afterImageChange callback and it is triggered with the correct path but even so it appears empty.

If I don't use the MvxImageViewLoader and directly load the path during ViewDidLoad it works fine even when I reload the image:

```
  using (var url = new NSUrl(ViewModel.MyImagePath)
      using (var data = NSData.FromUrl(url))
           myImage.Image = UIImage.LoadFromData(data);
```

If I specify a default image path, the default image is shown but the main image doesn't appear as before.

Any idea why the MvxImageViewLoader doesn't reload the larger image?

Comment: You forget to mention which version your are running.

Comment: Hi @Cheesebaron I am using the latest stable release of MvvmCross 3.5.1

Comment: Any chance you could try the latest 4.0.0 beta and see if it is still a problem with that?

Comment: I updated to beta but get the error while the app is launching
Assertion failure in -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3512.29.5/UIApplication.m

I am planning to update my Xamarin libs later on. Might fix this error.

Comment: @doorman hi guys have you fixed/found workaround for this bug ?

Comment: Hi @AndriiTsok I ended up using Akavache caching library to load the images https://github.com/akavache/Akavache